# Spring : Does <context:component-scan /> instantiate all beans defined in the base package?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="packageA" />
```

Does this instantiate all beans defined in `packageA.*`(base package and sub-packages) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "does it apply to subpackages automatically", then the answer is **yes**.

Beans in the base package and sub packages will be found by Spring when using `component-scan` or `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will search every class within this package.

No, it will not instantiate the beans, but by component-scan you are telling your spring application about the packages where it should search for Components and Beans.

You can verify this by declaring beans in
packageA.subpackage1.* and packageA.subpackage2.*

but put

```
<context:component-scan base-package="packageA.subpackage1" />
```

put some logging in your beans and you won't see any logs coming from bean methods declared in packageA.subpackage2.* package.

Comment: I think your answer is slightly confusing: `component-scan` itself isn't responsible to instantiate beans but it will lead to beans of the packages and subpackages being instantiated if needed.